Physical interpretation of the semilinear Dirichlet problem
As a non-physicist student, I’ve been trying to gain some intuition on the problem I’m studying, namely
\begin{equation}\begin{cases} -\Delta u + f(u) = h, \; \text{in } D \subset \mathbb{R}^n\\
u=0, \; \text{on } \partial D \end{cases}\end{equation}
As a mathematical point of view, I think $h$ is understood as a perturbation, and $f$ could be seen as how the solution somehow interacts with itself, but I would not be able to tell when this equation would arise in physics, and what it would mean.
Thanks a lot!

Physically, this can be identified with the Helmholtz equation for $f(u)=ku$ and $h=0$. The Helmholtz equation can be obtained from the wave equation for harmonic solutions of the form $\exp(i\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{x}-\omega t)$.

There are many instances of such equations. I'll assume that you are considering real valued $u$. I will just mention two.
You encounter such equations in Landau Ginzburg theory, with $u$ the order parameter and $h$ the conjugate variable, and $f$ the derivative of the potential (some kind of force). The simplest example would be $\phi^4$ theory, i.e. the Ising model, with $u$ a real scalar and $f$ a cubic polynomial. In a magnetic analogy, $u$ would be the local magnetisation, $h$ the external magnetic field causing the bias, and $f$ deriving from a quartic potential representing interactions.
You also have such equations for (stationary) reaction diffusion equations with only one component. $u$ now represents the density of the component, with the Laplacian the diffusion term and $f$ the reaction term.
For small values of $h$, you can solve the problem perturbatively about the trivial solution $u=0$ by rewriting it as:
$$
u = \Delta^{-1}h+\Delta^{-1}f(u)
$$
You can interpret the perturbation series as tree Feynman diagrams (the edges are the propagators, $\Delta^{-1}$ and the internal vertices the monomials of $f$ and the leaves $h$), and that is one way of seeing that the nonlinear term causes self interactions.
Hope this helps.

It does, thanks a lot!
